# youtube video url not working on "video-react" npm module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application I need to show videos. I am using "video-react" npm module.

When I am giving "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPiFVXsdvXs" url as source  of player than it is not working.

Although "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4" url is working   properly.

```
 <Player
          autoPlay
          poster="/assets/poster.png"
          src={this.state.mediaUrl}
          //src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
            //src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPiFVXsdvXs"
        />
```

Comment: When you say it is "not working properly" please be more descriptive - what does it show? what is in the console? etc

Comment: the src should be https://youtu.be/QPiFVXsdvXs not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPiFVXsdvXs . Can you change AND CHECK

Comment: I don't see any mention on https://video-react.js.org/ that "a youtube link" would work. What made you think it's supposed to? It clearly expects a video as source, not "a webpage that might have a video on it".

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-player to display video. for that install npm i react-player package.

```html
<ReactPlayer
  url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPiFVXsdvXs"
  light={true}
  playing
  controls
/>
```